# Mailbox programming in iphone?

Tags: iphone, email

I want saved email addresses of different users, and I want to open mailBox's new mail when I click the email, same as phonebook email in iphone,

what should I to do ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `MFMailComposeViewController` class, and the implement `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol,

**First to send a message:**

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"Hello there." isHTML:NO]; 
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

**Once you sent you will get delegate callback in `mailComposeController` :**

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                        error:(NSError*)error;
{
  if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
    NSLog(@"It's gone!");
  }
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new message within Mail:

```
NSString *subject = @"The subject";
NSString *body = @"The message";
NSString *address = @"mail@address.com";
NSString *cc = @"mail@address.com";
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?cc=%@&subject=%@&body=%@", address, cc, subject, body];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```